# How do I see who is using my Perl subroutines from a Unix command line?

Tags: perl, unix

I searched but I could not find if there is any command that will allow me to see which Perl files are requiring another Perl file.  I am just trying to see a sample program that uses a specific subroutine in one the Perl files that already exists in my work database but am unsure how to do this or if it is even possible.  For example, one file might say:

```
require $file_a or die;
&subroutine_a_from_file_a();
```

and the other file would have the subroutine:

```
sub subroutine_a_from_file_a{
    # do stuff necessary for another file
}
```

Is there any way to see the first file from the Unix command line if I did not already know about it's existence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could just grep for any file mentioning the sub in question:

```
find / -type f -exec grep -l 'subroutine_a_from_file_a' "{}" \;
```

Comment: Thank you.  This was exactly what I was looking for.  Nice name btw.

Comment: He is skinny, he just should be fat!

Answer (score 1):

There are some possible solutions here:-

http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=118441

'grep' is good to a point, but wouldn't work in the example you have because the file is named from a variable.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this link.  Grep did work, I believe it is just because it is searching for the name of the subroutine, so anywhere that specific combination of characters appears should match the grep search.